# Default route is not working with Area route

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am creating an application in ASP.NET Core 2.2. In the Startup.cs file there was already a default route and I defined one other route for an admin area:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "admin",
        template: "{area=Admin}/{controller=User}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
```

The admin area is authorized by an `Admin` role using `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]`. But when I start the application, it's calling that area route by default, although the user can't see anything and he gets an unauthorized page. Why is the application using the area route as the default route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By saying `{area=Admin}` you are making the `area` part optional. So a route not containing an area will also be matched by that (with `Admin` as the chosen area).

If you want to make sure that only a path `/Admin/` triggers your area, you could do it like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "admin",
    template: "Admin/{controller=User}/{action=Index}/{id?}",
    defaults: new { area = "Admin" });
```

You can also use this shortcut method which also sets up a route constraint for your area:

```
routes.MapAreaRoute("admin", "Admin",
    "Admin/{controller=User}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Also, the order in which you register your routes is also important. In general, the first route template that matches a route will be used. So since your admin route is rather specific, you should probably list that first, and only then fall back to a default route.

As the [documentation on routing areas in MVC explains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#areas):

> Conventional routing is order-dependent. In general, routes with areas should be placed earlier in the route table as they’re more specific than routes without an area.